# Python3: Surpress specific console output on request

Tags: python, printing, output

I have a Python script, call it SCRIPT_1 that runs two other scripts, SCRIPT_2 and SCRIPT_3.

SCRIPT_2 is an active process that prints periodic messages (in this case, network traffic). 
SCRIPT_3 is an active CLI interface that allows input and thus where I can insert commands.
For example, typing and entering "reset" resets the network nodes.

Both scrips output to the same terminal session. This is intended and desirable since I will be using these scripts on all kinds of devices and might not always be easier to manage multiple screens.
To do so they use the generic "print" command.

However, because both processes print stuff to the same screen, I'd like to be able to give a command to SCRIPT_3 to not show the printouts of SCRIPT_2.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do that. 
Preferably, I could give a command "show_output" "hide_output" to SCRIPT_3 and the printouts stop. Ideally, I also could keep using the same print() command for both scripts since SCRIPT_2 is very big. (it hides an entire system and that entire system uses print()).

Any advice on how to go about this?

The code for SCRIPT_3 is, at the moment, not much more than this:

```
    def run(self):
    print("Type 'help' for available commands, 'test' to run test.")
    while True:
        params = input('>> ')
        params = params.split()


        if params[0] is not None and params[0] == "help":
            print("Available commands are:")
        elif params[0] is not None and params[0] == "test":
            print("Test")
        elif params[0] is not None and params[0] == "reset_nodes":
            print("Resetting all nodes")
            asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.iot_net.reset_all_nodes(), self.loop)
        elif params[0] is not None and params[0] == "":
            pass
        elif params[0] is not None and params[0] == "done":
            pass
        else:
            print("Unknown command.")
    sys.exit()
    print("Bye.")
```

EDIT:
Answer to a relevant comment, thanks!

SCRIPT_1 runs the other scripts as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = SCRIPT_1()

    # set up the IoT Network API
    iot_net = SCRIPT_2()

    # Sven: Give time to establish connections
    time.sleep(3)
    # set up the resource pool
    pool_object = Pool(iot_net, LOCATION)
    asyncio.ensure_future(pool_object.run())

    # set up message aggregator
    payload_object = Aggregator()
    asyncio.ensure_future(payload_object.run())

    # start the web api
    api = WebAPI()
    api.run(pool_object, payload_object)

    # MUST START LAST
    tasks = []
    for x in range(BATCH_SIZE):
        tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(iot_net.consume_deployment(x)))
    asyncio.wait(tasks)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    cm_cli     = SCRIPT_3(iot_net,loop)
    cm_cli.start()

    try:
        # asyncio.ensure_future(print_content('http://google.com'))
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Comment: How does SCRIPT_1 run SCRIPT_2 and SCRIPT_3?

Comment: Relevant! Sorry I forgot, augmented post.